# Match with concatenate across google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this formula:

=IF(MATCH($A1&B$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100,0), 1, 0)

I expect the formula in Sheet 1, Column C to produce all ones as in Excel but I only get a 1 when there is a row with a,b in Sheet 2:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pyuWNNU7S07AC7d4zMvXft5pEz3AeAbeHcQp-wNsXpo/edit?usp=sharing

Why is this and is there a way around it that will also work in Excel?

---

Edit to clarify:
I want to be able to look up the value in two cells concatenated, e.g., $A1&B$1 and check if this matches any item in the list:
[Sheet2!$A$1&$B$1, Sheet2!$A$2&$B$2, Sheet2!$A$3&$B$3, ...]

Other details that may be important:
In my actual example, the columns I am looking at are not adjacent.

I would like the result to be compatible with as many spreadsheet programs as possible, especially Excel, Google Sheets and LibreOffice.

I will be writing the formula using openpyxl for Python.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Please share your sheet view only

Comment: @JohnA OK. I have linked it above

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Could you clarify what you mean by `Column C to produce all ones as in Excel`?

Comment: @Iamblichus I have edited the question. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not sure I understand this. Can you share a screenshot of the desired output so that this is clarified?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe MATCH() is the appropriate function. There are lots of other options like vlookup(), index().

I like using the QUERY() function personally.

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!$A1:$B, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A = '"&A1&"' AND B = '"&B1&"' LABEL COUNT(A) ''",0)
```

QUERY() shows #N/A when no results are found so we can wrap the above function accordingly

```
=IF(ISNA(query(Sheet2!$A1:$B, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A = '"&A1&"' AND B = '"&B1&"' LABEL COUNT(A) ''",0)), "",query(Sheet2!$A1:$B, "SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE A = '"&A1&"' AND B = '"&B1&"' LABEL COUNT(A) ''",0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. The QUERY method seems useful. Does it work in Excel too though?

Comment: I have not used Excel much since my organization is a google shop. But it looks like Excel has a Power Query Editor. Too bad Microsoft has not implemented a QUERY() based on SQL as Google has done. The PQE is like a fancy Filter and the advance give us obtuse code

Comment: Here is an example of the advanced screen

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Contract Name", type text}, {"Last Trade Date", type text}, {"Strike", type number}, {"Last Price", type number}, {"Bid", type number}, {"Ask", type number}, {"Change", type number}, {"% Change", type text}, {"Volume", type text}, {"Open Interest", Int64.Type}, {"Implied Volatility", type number}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Strike] = 30))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that. I have edited my question now to provide more details that I probably should have added to start with. I'll see if this is possible to implement from openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to use MATCH is making both parameters (search_key and range) expressed as brackets keys, the answer is:

=IF(MATCH({$A1}&{B$1},{Sheet2!$A$1:$A$100}&{Sheet2!$B$1:$B$100},0), 1, 0)

You MUST press Mayus + enter to asign the formula as an array